# iOS8: Adding Gradient To UIButton Using IB

Tags: ios8, uibutton, storyboard, autolayout

I'm using Auto-Layout.  I have three `UIButton`'s that take up the entire screen.  Each UIButton has a different background color and I would like to add Gradient to each.

Following are the steps that I took:

1. Subclassed `UIButton` called `CustomButton`
2. Assigned each of these buttons `CustomButton` in `Identity Inspector`.
3. In CustomButton class, I declared two `@IBInspectable` properties.
4. I pass in these colors through the IB.

Below is how I configuered the gradient in CustomButton:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class CustomButton: UIButton {

    @IBInspectable var topColor: UIColor!
    @IBInspectable var bottomColor: UIColor!

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        let gradientColors: [CGColor] = [topColor.CGColor, bottomColor.CGColor]
        let gradientLocations: [Float] = [0.0, 1.0]

        let gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = gradientColors
        gradientLayer.locations = gradientLocations
        self.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    }
}
```

However, the gradient is still not showing.  What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

This isn't working either:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class CustomButton: UIButton {

    @IBInspectable var topColor: UIColor!
    @IBInspectable var bottomColor: UIColor!

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder:aDecoder)

        let gradientColors: [CGColor] = [topColor.CGColor, bottomColor.CGColor]
        let gradientLocations: [Float] = [0.0, 1.0]

        let gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = gradientColors
        gradientLayer.locations = gradientLocations
        gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
        self.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, don’t create layers in `-drawRect`—it’s meant for drawing into the current Core Graphics context, and can get called multiple times, which will result in creating a new gradient layer each time. Instead, override `-initWithCoder:` and create the layer there.

The reason your layer isn’t showing up at all is because its frame isn’t set and is defaulting to `CGRectZero`, i.e. a 0✕0 rectangle. When you create the layer, you should be setting its `frame` to the view’s `bounds`. If the view’s going to change size, you should also override `-layoutSubviews` and update the layer’s frame there.

Comment: Thanks.  I did an update.  It's crashing at `let gradientColors: [CGColor] =...` line.  Am I on the right path?

Comment: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`